# Override EditorForModel Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, editorfor

You can provide alternate templates for individual types, but is it possible to override the template that wraps the label, field and validation up.

Change:

```
<div class="editor-label"><label for="Content">Content</label></div>
<div class="editor-field"><input class="text-box single-line" id="Content" name="Content" type="text" value="" /> </div>
```

To:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="Content">Content</label>
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Content" name="Content" type="text" value="" /> </div>
```

Rich

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write an Object.ascx template and perform your own logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This just overrides the base type. What I'm looking is a why to override the template that contains the label, field and validation template. If that is possible.

Comment: It's the Object template that does that. It iterates through each property of an object and renders those three things. Check out Brad Wilson's series on the topic http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: Beg your pardon. Found the Brad Wilson blog under my own steam. Initially I had been expecting to find a single item template, rather than an iterator template and as a result didn't understand what I was seeing in your example. Thanks again.