# Editor template being wrapped whilst being used with EditorFor extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Html.EditorFor extension does a great job of generating HTML for model properties but I can't change the classes that are generated around the form fields. (editor-label, editor-field)

```
<div class="editor-label">
<label for="ContactNumber">Contact number</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
<input class="text-box single-line" id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is create my own editor template, which I have done, but the method just wrapps what I've done within the code that's already being generated.

So this is my template

```
@model System.String

<div class="field-wrap">
    <div class="MyOwnClass">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m)
    </div>
    <div class="MyOwnClass">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the output being generated when calling Html.EditorForModel().

```
<div class="editor-label">
 <label for="ContactNumber">Contact number</label>
</div>

<div class="editor-field">

 <div class="field-wrap">

    <div class="MyOwnClass">
        <label for="ContactNumber">Contact number</label>
    </div>

    <div class="MyOwnClass">
        <input id="ContactNumber" name="ContactNumber" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How do I implement a Template that actually renders what I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630048/override-editorformodel-template) - i.e. to override the object.ascx template.